# Use std::begin(), std::end() to convert ArrayXd to stl vector,

Tags: c++, arrays, eigen

It seems to me that I should be able to use `std::begin()` and `std::end()` to convert `ArrayXd` to `std::vector<double>`; however, when I tried it in the following code, my attempt failed. My understanding is that `.data()` method on any `Eigen` object returns a pointer to a continuous block of memory similar to c style array. Therefore, since I can use `std::begin()`, `std::end()` on a c style array, I expected that to work with `.data()` as well. However, Eigen classes are templated, and I think this is what causes me problems, but don't see a way to fix this. How should this be done?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

using namespace Eigen;

int main()
{
  ArrayXd e_array(5);
  e_array << 3,4,5,6,7;  

  double c_array[] = {1,2,3,4,5};

  //Fails 
  // std::vector<double> my_vec(std::begin(e_array.data()), std::end(e_array.data()));

  // Works
  // std::vector<double> my_vec(e_array.data(), e_array.data() + 5);


  // Works
  // std::vector<double> my_vec(std::begin(c_array), std::end(c_array));
  // Works
  // std::vector<double> my_vec(c_array, c_array + 5);

  return 0;
}
```

My error message(First lines, the whole message is long):

> error: no matching function for call to
>   ‘begin(Eigen::PlainObjectBase >::Scalar*)’
>   std::vector my_vec(std::begin(e_array.data()),
>   std::end(e_array.data()))

Comment: "Therefore, since I can use `std::begin()`, `std::end()`" - The sentence prior said `.data()` returns a pointer to contiguous memory **similar** to a C-style array. Similar is not  *the same*. Arrays are not pointers. You cannot use `std::begin()` and `std::end()` on a raw dynamic pointer. I simply doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::begin(vec.data())` cannot work because data() returns a raw pointer which cannot convey the number of elements in the vector.  This version is the best one of yours:

```
std::vector<double> my_vec(e_array.data(), e_array.data() + 5);
```

And slightly better:

```
std::vector<double> my_vec(e_array.data(), e_array.data() + e_array.size());
```

And you may also be able to do this with many containers, but not with Eigen's ArrayXd in particular, because it lacks `begin()` and `end()` (related: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/bz/show_bug.cgi?id=231).

```
std::vector<double> my_vec(foo.begin(), foo.end());
```

Comment: or `std::vector<double> my_vec(std::begin(e_array), std::end(e_array));`, which is what the OP was *trying* to do.

Comment: @o11c: I think that won't work because ArrayXd doesn't have begin() and end(): http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/classEigen_1_1Array.html

Comment: but `std::begin` and `std::end` can be implemented on types that don't have `.begin` and `.end` as member functions - for example, they are on C-style arrays.

Comment: @o11c: yes, they *can*.  But for ArrayXd, the type we are talking about here, they are not.